# Why I am not able to create virtual enviroment on a project directory?

Tags: django-rest-framework, virtualenv

I was following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyei2iDA4Hs&list=PLillGF-RfqbbRA-CIUxlxkUpbq0IFkX60 , when I typed "pipenv shell" it created a virtual environment on my root directory with the name same as my username but I wanted to create virtual env on the project directory.

[my code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ib54.png)
I didn't want "(ryuk) ryuk@ryuk ~ $"
instead I want something like this "(pipenv)ryuk@ryuk ~/github repos/react-django $"

Comment: I edited it. Is it now explaining my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the current directory with the command `cd /path/to/the/dir`:

```
cd ~/"github repos/react-django"
```

Double quotes to avoid problems with the space in the directory name.